# C - How create an array that points to different datatypes?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I want to create an array that has a double value at it's zeroth index, a pointer that points to a double array, and a pointer that points to an integer array. Is this possible? Or should I use a structure?

Something like this:
[pointer description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgV9d.png)

Comment: Use a pointer to `union` incorporating all of these types. Or `void*`...

Comment: Please tell us  ore about this array. What should be contained in index 1,2,3 etc.? The image you're linking to is very unclear.

Comment: It really sounds like you want a structure, not an "array". What is the *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you want an "array"? What are you supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do that, with a void pointer for example.

BUT, don't go for this approach, since what you need (based on what you said), is a **struct**, with fields a double, a pointer to a double array, and a pointer to an integer array, like this:

```
struct myStruct {
   double  v;
   double* d_ptr;
   int*    i_ptr;
};
```

Comment: No it's the wrong direction @Ayatana. Please use a *struct*.

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are for storing a list of values of the same type, while a structs are for storing a list of values of differing types.

So what you want is a `struct`:

```
struct data {
    double val0;
    double *dbl_list;
    int *int_list;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `struct` to make the list data structure and that struct contains a `union` to hold the different type of elements, for example:

```
typedef struct MY_LIST {
    int utype;
    union {
        int intval;
        double dblval;
    } u;
    struct MY_LIST *next;
} t_myList;
```

Integer `utype` will hold an indicator of what is stored in the union (e.g. value `1` means the integer and value `2` means the double).

You can address an element now as:

```
t_myList *p;
...
if (p->utype==1)
    printf("integer value %d\n", p->u.intval);
...
p= p->next;
```

Comment: But this has become a list. I want random access.

Comment: Your image doesn't show that. It shows pointers. However, then you can declare an array of these structs (without the `next` element). I have given you some ideas; maybe it is time to use it to make what you want yourself.